# .NET Core ASP.NET app unable to load unmanaged DLLs under IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

In our ASP.NET Core web api, we are attempting to load unmanaged C++ code from a DLL that we included in our published folder.

This fails upon calling the endpoint that loads the DLL. The exception is as follows:

```
DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'libespeak-ng' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

It should be noted that this DLL loads and functions fine when the app is run through Visual Studio. Running the app in Kestrel with the dotnet command also works properly, on the same server. It is only inside of IIS that the app fails to load this DLL.

We have made sure the IIS user (as well as the default app pool) has permission to read and execute the DLL. We've tried placing the DLL in the app bin folder, in System32, in SysWOW64, and in the various inetsrv directories. None of this has resolved the issue.

Looking at ProcMon, it seems like IIS does not even attempt to load the DLL. Dependency Walker doesn't reveal any missing dependencies that aren't also missing when running it with Kestrel on any machine.

Comment: have you tried registering the dll? running `regsvr64` or `regsvr32` for 32 bit?

Comment: @AntonToshik running that doesn't seem to produce any errors, though it also doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Is your DLLs 32bits or 64bits? Could it be linked to the fact that under VS your dotnet core binary is running in 32 bits hence able to load the DLL while under IIS it would be running in 64bits and failing to load it? Moreover, which user account are used for the binary using IIS and using Ketrel directly? If different, can you try to force the usage of the same user account for IIS ?

Comment: @Daboul I've now forced the project to build in 64-bit, still doesn't resolve the problem. I can confirm the IIS is running 64 bit and the DLL is 64 bit as well.

Comment: Moreover, which user account are used for the binary using IIS and using Ketrel directly? If different, can you try to force the usage of the same user account for IIS ?

Comment: @Daboul even forcing the application pool to run as Administrator, which is what Kestrel runs as, doesn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

After many hours of struggling, and attempting the solutions commented by other users, we finally figured out the issue.

The DLL was trying to access some Windows APIs that did not exist in Windows Server 2012 R2, apparently. Once we updated the server to the latest windows server version, everything worked without issue.

Comment: It's worked for me, after then 40 hours... Thank you so much.